# How do I keep Glaze for Gingerbread cookies translucent

Tags: glaze

need to glaze cookies that will be help at a cold temp. cookies are translucent when glazed, if refrigerated, they become chalky and opauque
looking for ideas on how to keep the glaze clear- 
glaze formula
powdered sugar - 100%
water - 24%
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can combine 1 part water to 3 parts sugar in a saucepan and heat until the sugar dissolves and the liquid is clear. Allow it to cool to just above room temperature before applying to your cookies. It will harden when cool and be translucent.

Food.com has a recipe and directions here: http://www.food.com/recipe/simple-cookie-glaze-345260

Comment: Lisa, this is an interesting idea. Have you tried it? Looking at the numbers, I would expect there to not be enough water to dissolve all the sugar well. Also, if you are basically making hard candy, isn't it too hard to bite off?

Comment: @rumtscho to make hard candy you would have to cook the mixture to at least soft crack stage 270°F/132°C the sugar will be dissolved before it gets this hot.

Comment: @DebbieM. Sure, the water will dissolve more sugar after it's heated, but you need to mix them when at least one of the substances is still room temperature. This is certainly more difficult than the traditional method of starting with unsaturated syrup and cooking out some water, and I suspect it is even more difficult than starting caramel with dry sugar (which is prone to irregular heating and sometimes burns or crystalizes). So I was asking if my hunch is correct (that it makes it fiddly) or if Lisa tried it and it went smoothly.

Comment: I tried cooking the glaze, that was my first try. It actually made it worse. Looks like using a thinner glaze may work. Also- testing a powdered sugar that does not have cornstarch added as an anti caking agent.

Comment: this is for high volume production BTW

Comment: Although I'm a bit confused about whether your glaze is translucent or clear, I used the @Lisa formula, using granulated sugar (not powdered/confectioner) which dried clear/see-through. The second I've used, thanks to Yelena Strokin, food blogger, has powdered sugar and water, but adds a small amount of butter and light corn syrup. In volume, it's 2 tablespoons water, 1 tablespoon butter, and 1 tablespoon light corn syrup for every 12 ounces of confectioners sugar (2.5 cups). http://www.melangery.com/2011/12/molded-gingerbread-cookies-with-clear.html